# Invited for a 'Follow Up' meeting, after an internal interview. What does this mean?

Tags: follow-up

Myself and three colleagues were all interviewed for the same role last Thursday. It would be a promotion for all of us.

We all received an email the next day saying they would get back to us early this week with feedback. I have now received an invite for a 'follow up' meeting tomorrow. I have since found out that mine is the last appointment of the day and also the shortest! I can't help but feel like this is a bad sign, can anyone advise if they think I should expect bad news?

Comment: There's no way we can really know the answer to this question, but if I had to guess I'd say you didn't get it.

Comment: There is 1 position available, 3 people apply. 2 people have follow up interviews that last X long, and one person has a FOI that lasts Y long. Sounds like you want you have the Y length interview :)

Comment: Expect the worst, and maybe you'll be surprised.

Comment: It's quite possible that that's just a result of scheduling.  They needed to fit in three meetings, they had two half hour slots and one 15 minute slot.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't help but feel like this is a bad sign, can anyone advise if they think I should expect bad news?

I suggest that it doesn't matter one way or the other at this point. Either you got the job or you didn't. Knowing what's coming in the meeting isn't going to change anything that you do.  It's also entirely possible that things change between now and the meeting.  Maybe as of right now, they're not planning on giving you the job, but you're #2 on the list and #1 for some reason drops out.  Who knows?

You can make yourself crazy trying to figure out these things.  I've found that not trying to guess at things that I can't control makes me much happier in life.  I suggest that this is an opportunity for you to practice not trying to predict the future.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a followup meeting means either an additional interview or that a decision has been made.

If yours is the shortest it likely means "welcome aboard"

Comment: I agree, long meetings are for explaining why you can't be hired.  Short meetings are typically "you're in".  Of course, there are other scenarios too, but one typically needs to explain a lot less in accepting a new employee.

Comment: Or, it takes a longer meeting to go over next steps for transition than it does to say "Sorry, not this time".  I wouldn't read too much into the length of the appointment.